# Global variable producing nothing in python

Tags: python

I have a program that has a global dictionary, "d", and I can print it out fine in a function but when I add or remove a value from it nothing happens.

```
d = {}

def main():
    global d

    # ADD SCORES
    leadFile = open("leaderboard.txt","r")
    leads = []
    lead = leadFile.readline()

    while lead != "":
        leads.append(lead)
        lead = leadFile.readline()

    leadFile.close()

    for lead in leads:
        fields = lead.split(",")
        d[fields[0]] = fields[1]

    print(d)

main()
```

Comment: Where do you call `main`?

Comment: This program looks ill-conceived. Please can you give some example input and expected output?

Comment: Why not taking d as an argument and returning the variable at the end of the function?

Comment: You're sure your ```leads``` array is not empty (i.e. you're sure you are actually appending anything at all to ```d```)? Analogical code works like a charm for me.

Comment: You don't have to declare `d` as global, because you are assigning to *keys* in `d`, not to `d` itself.

Comment: @roganjosh im expecting for it to print a dictionary with values inside, rather than just an empty dictionary

Comment: As an aside, this is an odd way to write the code. Files are iterable; `leads = [line for line in leadFile]` or even just `leads = list(leadFile)`.

Comment: Now I had to delete my comment because @chepner wrote the same and with better wording. :(

Comment: @jef that wasn't what I asked. I have a rough idea of what you expect to happen but I asked for a small example. There's no use in me using conjecture to fill the gaps; you _almost certainly_ don't want `global` here, for a start. And there's other oddities. I, or others, can't address them without a concrete idea on what you expected to happen here without a [mcve]

Comment: Since you don't use a full path the file "leaderboard.txt" might not be the file you expect to open. Did you try to print `lead` in the `while` loop?

Comment: I agree with what many others have said. Forgot chasing a solution, there are bigger issues to attend to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

leaderboard.txt:

```
a,10
b,20
c,30
d,40
e,50
```

running your code:

```
$ python test.py
{'a': '10\n', 'b': '20\n', 'c': '30\n', 'd': '40\n', 'e': '50\n'}
```

test.py contains a copy/paste of your posted code. There are definitely some areas for improvement in the code, but this was taken as posted.

For what it's worth, you could simplify the code like this:

```
d = {}

def main():
    global d
    d.update(dict(item.split(',') for item in open('leaderboard.txt', 'r')))
    print(d)

main()
```

If you don't have a very specific need to use the global variable, it's usually considered cleaner to pass objects as function parameters:

```
d = {}

def main(my_dict):
    my_dict.update(dict(item.split(',') for item in open('leaderboard.txt', 'r')))
    print(my_dict)

main(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to present an alternative to the "simplified" code in the other answer.

```
d = {}

def main():
    with open("leaderboard.txt", "r") as leader_file:
        d.update(dict(line.strip().split(',') for line in leader_file))

    print(d)

main()
print(d)
```

As you can see you don't need `global`. As a bonus this code strips the line ends from the data.

Nevertheless I wouldn't use a global variable here but use a parameter if you want to use an existing dictionary.

```
d = {}

def main(data):
    with open("leaderboard.txt", "r") as leader_file:
        data.update(dict(line.strip().split(',') for line in leader_file))

main(d)
```

Comment: While I don't disagree with you (and I considered removing the global in my answer), bottom line is that the question is framed in terms of the global variable. Even though it's possible to remove it, doing so creates an answer to a question that OP didn't ask. You're moving the goalposts.